# how to render files in twig file Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony

Files not displayed in twig (HTML )file in Symfony 3 I have used image path but it still not display so anyone can help me how to resolve this bug

Comment: Please provide a more accurate description of your problem. Also, why tag it Laravel 5?

Comment: image src="{{image.url }}" its working for me

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this bug by using that syntax: in image src, u write like that src="{{images.url}}" this syntax URL is the path of the image that has to save in database